# Is there a way to move text cursor on Mac using Trackpad?

Tags: macos, trackpad

In iOS, one can enter Trackpad mode by pressing and holing the <kbd>Space</kbd> key on the software keyboard to quickly move around the cursor in a text entry field.

Is there a way to do the same using Trackpad in MacBooks? I want to be able to use the Trackpad to move the cursors while coding.

Comment: How do you intend to differentiate between moving the mouse pointer and moving the cursor for text entry ?

Comment: I want my MacBook to have some feature like this: while I am pressing the `command` key, if I touch my trackpad, it should move the cursor for text entry without moving the mouse.